# Way of searching 30,000 SQL Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am about to make a simple search facility on my website, where a user will enter around 2-4 keywords which will get searched in two columns in a table in my MS SQL database. One column is a varchar (50) called title and one column is a varchar(2500) called description. There will be about 20,000-30,000 records potentially at any one time to search.

The keywords will need to return "the best matches" - you know the kind you get on search pages like ebay that return the closest matches. The way I was thinking of doing this is seems kind of naive - I thought I can read all 30,000 records of the table into and object like this:

```
public class SearchableObject
{
    string Title {get; set;}
    string Description {get; set;}
    int MatchedWords {get; set;}
}
```

Then create a List of that object e.g List go through all 30,000 records, populate the List, find out the ones that match most times and return the top 10 using something like

```
 if Description.contains(keyword1);
```

But then find out how many times it occurs in the string to populate the MatchedWords field.

### My question is, is this the best way to do this? If not, what would be?

Comment: Load the entire table into memory and search through it that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

full-text index search will do the trick.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547.aspx

Comment: Agreed.  Create a full-text index on the table and they you can query it using something like this:

    select * 
    from   tablename
    where  contains(*, 'word1 word2 word3')

There are also more advanced ways to do this that will use stemming, return a match score, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a full text indexing solution.  MS SQL Server 7 and later has a [full text indexing engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) built in ([here's a decent overview article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-full-text-search-language-features/)).  You could also consider using external products such as Lucene (available for [Java](http://lucene.apache.org/) and [C#/.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)).

Answer (score 2):

i think you only want to use C# to parse the search parameters, not actually perform the searching and aggregation... So no, it's not really the best way. Use SQL Server to do the search heavy-lifting.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at lucene for .net, that will allow full index of your text.

http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

the .net developers on this site may be able to tell you if there are any better alternatives

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Java or C#, I'd recommend [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) or [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Use a full-text search engine such as [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/). There exists also a  [.NET version](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/).

Comment: why use an external search engine when an internal engine exists within SQL Server?

Comment: Lucene and the SQL Server's built-in search engines have different feature sets and performance profiles for different data sets.