# SQL Server Search, how to return the total count of rows?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, select, count

I have another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779012/search-function-sql-server) which resulted in this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        a.ArticleID, 
        COUNT(*) AS KeywordMatch,
        a.Headline,
        a.ShortDescription,
        a.CategoryID,
        a.ArticleSectionImage,
        a.DatePublished
    FROM 
        Article a
    JOIN SearchWords sw ON a.ArticleID = sw.ArticleID
    WHERE
        EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT 
              1 
            FROM 
              iter_charlist_to_tbl(@temp, ' ') s 
            WHERE
              s.nstr = sw.SearchWord
        )
        AND
            a.ArticleState = 3  
    GROUP BY 
        a.ArticleID, a.Headline, a.ShortDescription, a.CategoryID, a.ArticleSectionImage, a.DatePublished
    ORDER BY (KeywordMatch) DESC, (a.DatePublished) DESC
```

I am using this along with Linq-to-SQL to create paging for the users. The problem is, that i need to know how many records my search returned (total rows), to display the correct arrows for the user.

This is my Linq-to-SQL Query:

```
  int iPageNum = pageNumber;
  int iPageSize = (int)pageSize;

  results = data.SearchArticles(searchString).Skip((iPageNum - 1) * iPageSize).Take(iPageSize).ToList();
```

Any ideas?

**Is my Linq-to-SQL pulling all records from the database? or does it create a query that only selects the records that i needs?
How can i peak at the query?**

Comment: What type of client are you writing? There's a reasonable chance that there is a paging component already written that you can just use.

Comment: I am adding the search function to our new "newspaper" site, small one. So i am doing everything myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to have two queries: one that returns a count, and another that returns the data.

You can put them both in one SP with multiple result sets to avoid an extra DB round-trip.  I explain a data paging example (including providing a count) in detail in my book: [Ultra-Fast ASP.NET](https://www.apress.com/9781430223832/).  My approach doesn't use LINQ (since it doesn't support multiple result sets), but it's also faster.

Here's a query that should count the number of rows in the result (not tested, but it should be close):

```
;WITH SearchArticles (aid, cnt, headline, descr, cid, img, datepub) as (  
SELECT DISTINCT
            a.ArticleID, 
            COUNT(*) AS KeywordMatch,
            a.Headline,
            a.ShortDescription,
            a.CategoryID,
            a.ArticleSectionImage,
            a.DatePublished
        FROM 
            Article a
        JOIN SearchWords sw ON a.ArticleID = sw.ArticleID
        WHERE
            EXISTS 
            (
                    SELECT 
                      1 
                    FROM 
                      iter_charlist_to_tbl(@temp, ' ') s 
                    WHERE
                      s.nstr = sw.SearchWord
            )
            AND
                    a.ArticleState = 3      
        GROUP BY 
            a.ArticleID, a.Headline, a.ShortDescription, a.CategoryID,
            a.ArticleSectionImage, a.DatePublished
) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SearchArticles
```

Comment: Well can't you in Linq just set a variable to OUTPUT and assign the count to that variable?
My problem was trying to reconstruct that query to return the number of rows.

Comment: Something like that only works if you also return all of the rows that you want to count. It sounds like what you want is a count of the total number of rows, but only return a subset of them for display. Right? To get a total count, you should be able to change your query to return only count(*), and eliminate the group by and order by clauses.

Comment: Well i tried that, but then it returns the number of keywords matches instead of the number of rows.

Comment: Oops; quite right; sorry. I'll update my answer with a better query.

Comment: Thanks; I would be interested to hear how you like the book.

Answer (score 1):

since you are fetching the entire set anyway with the data.SearchArticles part why not do this:

```
var results = data.SearchArticles(searchString);
var count = results.Count();

results = results.Skip((iPageNum - 1) * iPageSize).Take(iPageSize).ToList();
```

Depends a lot on the size of the return results as to whether this is OK.

Comment: The general idea was to avoid fetching the entire result set... Why is it returning the entire record set?
I am trying to find a way to see the SQL query that was produced through this statement.
It will return a lot of rows if everything is to be pulled.

Comment: Well if i were to do that, then i would enumerate the results more then once and get an error message.

Comment: If you want to avoid pulling the entire set then I would recommend a stored procedure which would return both the paged set and the total count. See this article: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Paging-Stored-Procedures.aspx

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments on the other answers:

SQL Server does not have built in paging.  So, by default, a query will fetch all rows.  If a query is not fetching all rows then your ResultSet object is doing the paging for you.  If the resultset is not paging, there is no need to iterate through all of the results in order to check its Count() property, it should just be set correctly as SQL Server does return the row count along with the data.

If you are worried about fetching too much data in one go and your resultset doesn't page, then you need to select the count first and then build a query that can return the page of data that you want.

Aside: You can leave the distinct off your select.  Since you are aggregating and grouping you are guaranteed to have distinct result already.